# Using easy_install with sklearn-pandas

Tags: python, easy-install, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to install sklearn-pandas.

On my attempt:

```
easy_install sklearn-pandas
```

I get the result:

> The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
> that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.
>
> This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not
> support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
> script by hand. Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall
> maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available.

I'm on windows 7 (I admit it!), using Python 2.7.3

This is the first time I've gotten any error like this.  Possible ideas I've explored are the more basic solutions:

The authors didn't write this package to be installed with easy_install
I have some sort of file permission problem (?)
There is some sort of dependencies issues

If anyone has ever gotten this error or has any insight into this please let me know! Much thanks.

Comment: Question: What's wrong with Windows 7? :(

Comment: I was just joking around... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `easy_install`, use pip!

(To install pip, follow this [other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12476379/700228)).

Additionally, you're probably going to need a compiler, development tools, and header files for Python (it's a whole 'nother bag of worms in Windows).

Assuming all is well, you can now

```
pip install sklearn-pandas
```

Comment: Also, you probably need to use `sudo` if you are not into a virtualenv, that is what the error message is probably telling you. However it's better practice if you install everything into a virtualenv.